# Firestore not storing new lines from TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When adding a string value from a TextField that includes line breaks (by tapping the new line button on your keyboard) to a Firestore field, the value inside Firestore isn't adding **\\n** to the value. Instead, it's just replacing it with an empty space. However, when displaying the string value in my app, it's displaying it with line breaks, which is confusing and problematic for me as the Firestore value doesn't include **\\n**.

Any reason why it's doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is just because of the way the Firestore console chooses to display strings, for compactness.  The data is always stored exactly as how you write it, and when you read it back in your app, it will be exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the heads up. Now got it working properly.